# Show/ hide divs based on URL Parameter

Tags: javascript

The code below shows and hides divs based on URL Parameter.  However, the URL parameter is going to show multiple items instead of just one (apples, oranges).  With the current code that doesn't work.  It will display nothing.  Instead I need it to show if it includes "apples" then show apple div.  If it includes "oranges", also show oranges.  This one is beyond me and I need some help configuring it.  Thanks in advance for any help!

The script I am using is below.  Like I said, the URL Parameter I will be using will be variations on "apples, oranges, bananas"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Parse the URL parameter
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    // Give the parameter a variable name
    var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('dc');

     $(document).ready(function() {

        // Check if the URL parameter is apples
        if (dynamicContent == 'apples') {
            $('#apples').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parameter is oranges
        else if (dynamicContent == 'oranges') {
            $('#oranges').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parameter is bananas
        else if (dynamicContent == 'bananas') {
            $('#bananas').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parmeter is empty or not defined, display default content
        else {
            $('#default-content').show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: To make sure I understand -- you want this to work with any value of the parameter instead of it being hardcoded for two or three values like "apples" and "oranges"?

Comment: What does your URL look like? There are several ways you could pass multiple values and how you solve this in your `$(document).ready` function depends on how you're passing the values. You could do, for example, `example.com/fruits?item=apple&item=orange` which is different than, say, `example.com/fruits?items=apple,orange`

Comment: my URL looks like this:http://www.example.com?dc=apples,%20oranges

Comment: From a web form, they will be able to select three options that are passed in the url.  On the confirmation page, I want a div to display for each of the options passed in the URL(Three options).  If they picked bananas, it will show bananas div.  If they picked bananas and oranges, it will show bananas div and oranges div.  If they picked apples and oranges, it will show only apples div and oranges div.

Comment: Correction:  my URL looks like this:http://www.example.com?dc=apples%0Aoranges

Answer (score 0):

1. The modern way:

   new URL("http://example.com/aa/bb/")

Returns an object with properties hostname and pathname, along with a few others.

The first argument is a relative or absolute URL; if it's relative, then you need to specify the second argument (the base URL). For example, for a URL relative to the current page:

```
new URL("/aa/bb/", location)
```

In addition to browsers, this API is also available in Node.js since v7, through require('url').URL

2. You can also use parse_url() function from Locutus project (former php.js).

Code:

```
parse_url('http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor');
```

Result:

```
{
  scheme: 'http',
  host: 'hostname',
  user: 'username',
  pass: 'password',
  path: '/path',
  query: 'arg=value',
  fragment: 'anchor'
}
```

Once it is parsed correctly, it should work the way you have used it.
Hope this helps..

Comment: Oh woah.  I think this is way over my head.  I'm not sure I see how this relates

Comment: @WebWilliam - this addresses only one part of the problem you're trying to solve -- this (`new URL`) is a much better way of getting the URL information than the `RegExp` way that you're currently using. This answer, however, does not at all address the main question: _How do you make it handle multiple parameters?_

Comment: Oh okay.  That makes sense.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the first part of your code the same (up to the document.ready line) here's how you change the part that displays the divs for each param:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (dynamicContent) {
    dynamicContent.split('\n').forEach(function(param) {
      $('#' + param).show();
    });
  } else {
    $('#default-content').show();
  }
});
```

With a url like `example.com/?dc=apples%0Aoranges` this would show the div with id `#apples` and the div with id `#oranges`

Comment: Hey this works for me except for one issue.  The URL is not example.com/?dc=apples%20oranges it is example.com/?dc=apples%0Aoranges.  The difference is the %0A which is what my form puts into the URL.  So it does not work. Is there something I need to change to make it work with %0A?

Comment: Yep, I edited my answer to fix that. Basically `%20` in a URL means white space (`' '`) and `%0A` means new line (`'\n'`) so I changed that character. @stephen-p also got this right in his answer except he added a coma as well. So once you get it working maybe also try to use his (better) way to get the search params (without the comma).

Comment: Elian, I feel I have tried everything to implement your solution but just cannot get it to work.  It works if I use just one fruit like apples, but if it is dc=apples%0Aoranges the page will not even load!  Im so sorry to be a pain about this, but please save me!

Comment: No worries, I know how frustrating things like this can be. First off, regardless of whats happening inside of jotform, are you positive that at the end it's directing visitors to the page that you control at `yoursite.com/?dc=apples%0Aoranges`. Is the URL exactly like that, or could there be some comma before `%0A` etc. Second, when the page doesnt load (shows up blank I guess) open the inspector (right click -> inspect, or press f12) and check the console tab to see for any errors. Opening the console is also required for the next debugging step which is what stephen is describing.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is how you handle multiple items in your `dc` parameter.

First, as @Shlomo's answer indicated, there is a better way to get the parameter value, by using the `URL` object instead of a `RegExp`. This would change your `function getParameterByName(name, url)` method to be like this:

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        let u = new URL(url);
        return u.searchParams.get('dc');
}
// try a call
let urlString = 'https://example.com?dc=apples%0Aoranges';
console.log( getParameterByName('dc', urlString) );
```

This is so simple you can do away with the method and just inline it.
What it gets you is the String `apples(linefeed)oranges` == `apples\u000Aoranges`
so you will want to *split* that string to get the components you want: `apples` and `oranges` — `string.split('\n')` which will give you an array: `["apples", "oranges"]`

Now when you act in your `$(document).ready(...)` you will want to check every element in the array.

```js
let urlString = 'https://example.com?dc=apples%0Aoranges';
$(document).ready(function() {
    const url = new URL(urlString)
    const dc = url.searchParams.get('dc')
    console.log(dc);
    const fruits = dc.split('\n');
    console.log(fruits);
    
    fruits.forEach(function(f) {
        // Check if the URL parameter is apples
        if (f == 'apples') {
            $('#apples').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parameter is oranges
        else if (f == 'oranges') {
            $('#oranges').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parameter is bananas
        else if (f == 'bananas') {
            $('#bananas').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parameter is empty or not defined, display default content
        else {
            $('#default-content').show();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.fruit {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fruit" id="default-content">No fruits have been chosen</div>
<div class="fruit" id="apples">apples</div>
<div class="fruit" id="oranges">oranges</div>
<div class="fruit" id="bananas">bananas</div>
```

There are more improvements that can be made to this, for example the `url`, `dc`, and  `fruits` assignments can be combined as a on-liner, and I may edit to show some of the improvements as time permits.

---

**Edits**

I've removed the comma — your first comment had comma-space, second comment just a newline, but I had left the comma in.

As @Elian's answer demonstrates, ***if*** your `id=` values *exactly* match the `dc` values you don't have to bother with the `if()` tests, you can use the dc value directly in the selector for your `.show()` — that was one of the improvements I implied.

Here is code that has that improvement, plus combining the steps and eliminating the intermediate variables. It also uses the Javascript ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in place of the `function(f)` parameter to the `forEach`:

```js
let urlString = 'https://example.com?dc=bananas%0Aoranges';
$(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        const fruits = new URL(urlString)
                       .searchParams.get('dc')
                       .split('\n');
        console.log(fruits);
        
        fruits.forEach(f => $('#'+f).show());
    }
    // If there is no `dc` value, the .split above will cause an error.
    // Catch it and show the default content.
    catch (err) {
        $('#default-content').show();
    }
});
```

```css
.fruit {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fruit" id="default-content">No fruits have been chosen</div>
<div class="fruit" id="apples">apples</div>
<div class="fruit" id="oranges">oranges</div>
<div class="fruit" id="bananas">bananas</div>
```

---

**Temporary** (would be a comment but needs formatting)

Go to the page where your javascript is running — the one that has the query string `?dc=apples%0Aoranges` ... go there however you would *normally* get there, by doing whatever you need in jotform.
On that page open your browser developer tools and type the following into your browser console:

```
let u = new URL(window.location.href);
let args = u.searchParams.get('dc');
let vals = [];
for (let i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
    vals.push(args.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

Now you have an array named `vals` ... just type that variable name into the console and it should display the contents of the array, which will be the numeric values of all the characters in the parameter value for `dc=`

```
vals
```

You should get a display that looks something like this:

```
(14) [97, 112, 112, 108, 101, 115, 10, 111, 114, 97, 110, 103, 101, 115]  #in Chrome
-or-
Array(14) [ 97, 112, 112, 108, 101, 115, 10, 111, 114, 97, … ] #in Firefox
```

Post it in a comment here using back-ticks to make it code.
(this output is when dc === `'apples\u000Aoranges'`)
This will show what *actual* characters are in the string, and therefore what to split on.

Comment: Stephen, thank you for the suggestions!  I have been trying to implement them for a couple of days now but can't get it to work.  Is the url https://example.com=bananas%0Aoranges used correctly?  should it include all of the three options?  Also, should it say ?dc=   ?  I am trying really hard to make this work, but the page just will not successfully load.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the url _should_ include `?dc=` ... I've fixed it now. It includes the `?dc=values%0Avalues` because I needed a sample URL to show the snippet working. You would probably use `window.location.href` like you do in your question; my `const url = new URL(urlString)` would become `const url = new URL(window.location.href)`. Some of how you handle this might depend on _how_ you supply those choices — but given your `getParameterByName` code I assumed it was the URL of the _current_ page, and your call `getParameterByName('dc');` implies the parameter name is "dc"

Comment: Yes, it is the url of the current page.  It is a confirmation page from Jotform.  The end of the url will say '?dc=apples%0Aoranges' or some variation of this with the three fruits. I still am not getting it to work though.  I deleted the line 'let urlString = 'https://example.com?dc=bananas%0Aoranges';' and replaced 'const fruits = new URL(urlString)' with 'const url = new URL(window.location.href)' like you suggested.  Am I totally missing the mark here?

Comment: Okay, I have an update, it now works if I have just one value in the url like apples, but if I add multiple like the following: dc=apples%0Aoranges , it cannot load the page.  What might I be missing here?  Thank you so much!

Comment: It is definitely an issue with %0A between values

Comment: It's hard to determine some things without being in your real environment — for example, you _might_ have to split on the literal string `%0A` instead of `\n`: `.searchParams.get('dc').split('%0A') but that wouldn't work in my browser console or here in a stack snippet, and I don't think that's the case, but that's the kind of thing that can differ between a real environment and a local test-case (snippets, console, etc) ... if you have any control over the parameter I'd send it separated with a comma, semi-colon, _something_ that's not a newline.

Comment: Seriously, if I could change how I send the values everything would be so much simpler, but JotForm does not allow that.  I also tried the literal string %0A but it didn't work either

Comment: I am temporarily adding to my answer — I _would_ comment here but need more formatting than comments allow. My 2nd example combines steps, but to debug you should do each step individually (like my 1st example) and step through it with the debugger, inspecting the results after each step, to find where it is not working.

Comment: I used chrome: `(15) [97, 112, 112, 108, 101, 115, 44, 44, 111, 114, 97, 110, 103, 101, 115]`

Comment: That output is when `?dc=apples%0Aoranges`

Comment: @WebWilliam - ok that's really weird. Those two `44` in the middle are _commas_, making the string `apples,,oranges` ... no `0x0A` `\u000A` `%0A` at all. Using `.split(',,')` would work; maybe better would be `.split(',')` even though it gives you an empty element.